# what is the result of $\int t^3 \sin\left( t^2\right)~dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

What should I do with the $\sin \left(t^2\right)$ ? Can I use trigonometric identities for this kind of problem ? Thanks in advance

Comment: start with   $u=t^2$ as your substitution.

Comment: Sub $u=t^2$, then get an integral of $u \sin{u}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with $x=t^2,$--so $\frac{dx}{dt}=2t,$ and so $t\,dt=\frac12dx,$ then use integration by parts on the resulting integral $$\frac12\int x\sin x\,dx.$$

Comment: Solved it. Thanks again. I didn't think it before to use the subs

Comment: Glad to help! Sometimes we end up having to use a mix of methods of integration. It's good to keep them all in mind.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Integration by parts is your tool with $u=t^2$.

**Added:** This gives

$$\int t^3\sin(t^2)dt=-\frac{t^2}{2}\,\cos( {t}^{2} ) +\int t\cos ( {t}^{2}) {dt}
 =\dots $$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int t^3 \sin(t^2) dt = \frac{1}{2}\int t^2\sin(t^2)(2tdt)=\frac{1}{2}\int t^2\sin(t^2)d(t^2)=\frac{1}{2}\int x \sin(x)dx$$ where $x=t^2$.

$$\int x \sin(x)dx = -x\cos(x)+\int\cos(x)dx=-x\cos(x)+\sin(x)+C $$

where $u=x$ and $dv=\sin(x)dx$ and $\displaystyle \int udv = uv - \int vdu$.

Therefore
$$\int t^3\sin(t^2)dt = \frac{1}{2}(-t^2\cos(t^2)+\sin(t^2))+K$$